# Unable to start Ado.Net Data Service in IIS6

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, wcf

I am trying to run a sample WCF ADO.Net Data Sertice on my IIS, which give me message

```
 The resource cannot be found.

    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

    Requested URL: /testing_wcf_service/WcfDataService1.svc/
```

Web Config File as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false">
            <!--<baseAddressPrefixFilters>
                <clear/>
                <add prefix="http://localhost/Testing_Wcf_Service/"/>
            </baseAddressPrefixFilters>-->
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>

    </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing"                >
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="App_tracelog.svclog"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
         name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"/>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This is working fine visual studio 2010, but does not start in IIS, i have searched a lot but could not find a solution.

Please can any one guide me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is System.Data.Entity v4 in the bin directory of the IIS app ? On my install of VS 2010, it is not in the GAC.

Comment: Yes i have given Copy Local = true;

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is file not found.

- It could be that the file is not where you expect it to be. Try browsing through IIS and see if you can find the flie.
- It could be that IIS does not know what to so with a SVC file. Is the correct version of the .Net framework installed? Is the type registered.
- From the config that you posted, I cannot see which binding you are using. The bindings supported by IIS 6 are limited.
- It could be a problem with the address in the client. The slash "/" after svc in the error message may be causing the problem.

Comment: I was able to get the error message it says:

1) args.Exception.Message = "The URL representing the root of the service only supports GET requests."


2) args.Exception.Message = "Resource not found for the segment 'mex'."

Comment: You need to configure the MEX endpoint see: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-_3A00_-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx